# php variable assign as false value

Tags: php, class

```
class Email
{       
    var $to = false;
    var $subject = false;   
}
```

I am a beginner in PHP. I have a class `Email`. In that class my variable `$to` gets assigned to `false` initially. It will be assigned to a value that is storred in another variable. I don't understand why this variable has this initial `false` value.

Can you please explain me why

Comment: Why are you using `var`? It's deprecated since the release of PHP5 **TEN** years ago.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a variable with value `false` and a variable with undefined value.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually a good idea to give variables a default value. That way, if the variable is used before it's reassigned, it will have a predictable value. `false` and `null` are useful initial values, as they can be distinguished easily from the values that will be assigned to the variables later.

`false` should generally only be used for variables that will hold boolean `true`/`false` values. For other variables, `null` is a better choice as a default. But this is mostly just a stylistic choice, either will usually work.

Comment: I think `false` is a horrible default value for a variable that won't remain a boolean in the future.

Comment: That's a philosophical question. I tend to favour solutions where any buggy code crashes as soon as possible, so if the variable is supposedly set by another bit of code, I would rather choose default values to cause as much nuisance as possible.

Comment: Uninitialized fields/properties in PHP contain `null` as value.

Comment: It's nice to be explicit.

Comment: That's why I initialize them in the same type they're going to be used (string, array, ...) wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to initialize your variables for predictability. For example:

```
foreach($stuff as $thing){
   $myVar[]=$thing;
}
doSomething($myVar);
```

If for whatever reason `$stuff` is empty (but hopefully still an array), `$myVar` will not exist after the loop and thus `doSomething()` will receive `null` as parameter instead of an `array`, resulting in at least a warning in your error log.

For functions/methods there's a similar reason:

```
function myFunc($stuff){
   $result=null;
   if($stuff==true)
       $result=array(1,2,3);
   return $result;
}
```

This may seem nice, because you've initialized your `$result` variable like a good student. But if `$stuff!=true`, `$result` will be `null` instead of an `array`. That may not seem much of a problem, but all the code that's using the `myFunc()` function will now have to be able to handle arrays **AND** null values (usually that means having to write unnecessary `if()` clauses for type checking).

Whereas if `myFunc()` always returned arrays (easily possible by initializing `$result` as `array()` instead), you have one less thing to worry about.

I kind of side-stepped your question, but hopefully this will still help you understand the concept.